# How to add two arraylist which has different data in android to get a single listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter, autocompletetextview

I have two arraylist. 
Arraylist one contains list of usrs in my chat app
ArrayList Two contains list of Groups in my chat app
What i am trying to do here is i want add user list with  list of groups in my chat app.

This is my first arraylist:
Here User is my  model class
userMap is HashMap which has all th User list

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
        for (User user : SocketSingleton.userMap.values()) {
            if (user.getId() != loggedUserId) {
                users.add(user);
            }
        }
```

Adapter for my first arraylist is

```
UserAdapter adapter1 = new UserAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.all_user_list_item,users);
```

This is my second arraylist which has all the groups
Here Channel is my model class for groups. And listchannels is HashMap which has all the groups.

```
 ArrayList<Channel> groups = new ArrayList<JoinedChannel>();
        for (Channel channel : SocketSingleton.listchannels.values()) {
            groups.add(channel);
        }
```

Adapter for second array list

```
 ChannelAdapter adapter2 = new ChannelAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.grouplist, groups);
```

I want to add the two lists So that i can set that single listview which contains all user and groups to a AutocompleteTextview
Please tell me a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

you can not combine two different adapter. As an option, is to create a separate class that will include something in common between two objects, like:

```
class ChatObject{
private int id;
prvate String title;
private boolean isUser;
}
```

dont forget to add constructor and get/set methods.

And when you are filling your arrays, also create your new Objects which will be using in your listview.

```
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
ArrayList<ChatObject > chatObjects= new ArrayList<ChatObject >();
        for (User user : SocketSingleton.userMap.values()) {
            if (user.getId() != loggedUserId) {
                users.add(user);
                ChatObject chatObject = new ChatObject();
                chatObject.setId(user.getId());
                chatObject.setTitle(user.getName());  //for example
                chatObject.setIsUser(true);
                chatObjects.add(chatObject);
            }
        }
```

and

```
ArrayList<Channel> groups = new ArrayList<JoinedChannel>();
        for (Channel channel : SocketSingleton.listchannels.values()) {
            groups.add(channel);
            ChatObject chatObject = new ChatObject();
            chatObject.setId(channel.getId());
            chatObject.setTitle(channel.getTitle());  //for example
            chatObject.setIsUser(false);
            chatObjects.add(chatObject);
        }
```

Hope it helps you ;)

Comment: After that i can set ChatObjrct arraylist to my view right?

Comment: i did like u said. Now i am setting this chatobjects to my autocomplete textview through adapter. what about the layout  .which can i set??